# The type initializer for 'OSGeo.OSR.OsrPINVOKE' threw an exception

Tags: c#, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to create a CoordinateTransformation to transform the SRS of a shapefile. However, on attempting to create one with the following method call:

```
var sourceSrs = new SpatialReference(Osr.SRS_WKT_WGS84);
```

I get the exception:

> The type initializer for 'OSGeo.OSR.OsrPINVOKE' threw an exception.

The detailed exception looks like:

[image: Exception]

Can anyone help?

Comment: I've already put this question on [GIS SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/198362/30966) as well.

Comment: That "bad image format" points to likely a difference in architecture -- something built for x86 trying to interact with something built for x64, for example. Much of that is probably hidden behind the P/Invoke calls that are internal to the library you're using.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: You are absolutely correct. So, I was running this code from a unit test. I set the 'Default Process Architecture' under Test Settings to x64. I still get this exception. Any other setting I need to change (which you can think of)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing the project to build for target platform of x64 helps. You can do that by going to Project Properties (Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>) > Build > Platform Target.

Further, if you are running the code from some unit test, do the same for the Unit Testing project **and** change the "Default Process Architecture" to x64. The "Default Process Architecture" can be changed from the Test (in VS menu items) > Test Settings > Default Processor Architecture > x64.